# How to create API key system and use it in the protected routes in Node js and express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

l created a back-end system using node js , express js , mongodb and added authentication with JSON Web Token to generate a token when a user login in . l also use the token to access protected routes.

The problem l have is **how to create API key system and use it  in the protected routes** .

l am using POSTMAN to test endpoint...

**l added this middleware to validate the API KEY before accessing an route**

```
const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.header("api-key")) {
    try {
      //let api_key = req.query.api_key; //version 1 with the querystring
      //let api_key = req.params.apikey; //version 2 with the URL params
      let api_key = req.header("api-key"); //version 3 using a header
      console.log(api_key);
      req.user = await User.findOne({
        apiKey: api_key,
        host: process.env.HOST,
      }).select("-password");
      if (req.user) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("Not authorized ,API Key is invalid");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized , API Key failed or invalid");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized ,no API key");
  }
});
```

[Attached is the image of postman used to test API , also included the API KEY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e4be.png)

Comment: What do you mean "protected routes"?

Comment: l mean routes that can only be accessed by logged in user

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: One way of solving this would be to factor out the code that handles JWT authentication into a middleware, and to then do the same for the API key authentication scheme. Then, the routes that need to use either (or both) of those authentication schemes can have those middlewares applied to them.

Comment: l edited the post to include the code and image to test the API , Please have a look and let me know if its OK

Comment: Does this article help? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-jwt-expressjs